# Python randomly throws the out of range error

Tags: python, arduino

I'm relatively new to Python and I'm trying to plot a list of measurements which I receive from an Arduino.

The problem I'm facing is that sometimes I get the out of range error, it works most of the time, but 1/4 of the time I get the error.

Here is my code:

```py
import serial                    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

# fuer Windos Nutzer sollte der Pfad
# COM4 oder aehnlich sein
# Baudrate muss der im arduino Programm entsprechen
# container fuer Messwerte
v = []
t = []

# Flag fuer das Startsignal

#####################################
# Zeichne Messwerte vom arduino auf #
#####################################
for lists in range(0,5):
    v.append([])
    t.append([])
    s = serial.Serial('COM5', baudrate=115200)
    start = False

    while True:
        val = s.readline().decode('ascii',errors='ignore').split()
        ## wenn Signalstring detektiert wird
        ## packe Daten in Container

        if start and val[0] != 'stop' and val[0] != 'start':
           v[lists].append(float(val[3])/1024 * 5)
           t[lists].append(float(val[1])/1000)

        ## wenn du noch nicht angefangen hast und das Kommando
        ## zum Anfangen bekommen hast: fang an
        print(val)
        if not start and (val[0] == 'start'):
            start = 1

        ## wenn du schon angefangen hast und das Kommando
        ## zum aufhoeren bekommen hast: hoer auf
        if start and val[0] == 'stop':
            break

    s.close()

o = np.array(v)
z = np.array(t)

print(o)

y = np.mean(o,axis = 0, out=None)
print("\n")

print(y)








### visualisiere die Daten
plt.figure(figsize=(18,9))     # groesse des Plots auf dem Schirm
plt.plot(z[1],y,'b.')          # mit blauen punkten 
plt.grid()                     # mit Gitter
plt.xlabel('t [milliseconds]') # mit Beschriftung der Ordinate
plt.ylabel('voltage [volts]')  # mit Beschriftung der Abzisse

plt.figure(figsize=(18,9))     # groesse des Plots auf dem Schirm
plt.plot(z[1],o[1],'r.')       # mit blauen punkten 
plt.grid()                     # mit Gitter
plt.xlabel('t [milliseconds]') # mit Beschriftung der Ordinate
plt.ylabel('voltage [volts]')  # mit Beschriftung der Abzisse

plt.show()                     # zeig es
```

Here I got what a portion of the decoded data transfer looks like, just before the error occurs:

```
['start']
['time:', '216', 'v:', '930']
['time:', '344', 'v:', '675']
['time:', '464', 'v:', '408']
['time:', '584', 'v:', '345']
['time:', '704', 'v:', '315']
.....
['time:', '98312', 'v:', '927']
['time:', '98832', 'v:', '927']
['stop']
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\maxia\OneDrive\privat\programieren\visual 
studio\phyton\arduino1_phyton\arduino1_phyton\arduino1_phyton.py", line 36, 
in <module>
if not start and (val[0] == 'start'):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Bitte übersetze deine Kommentare.

Comment: when `val` is empty, there is no element with index `0` and therefor `val[0]` throws the error. please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . that would have led to the solution.

Comment: can you print `val` before the conditional statement?

Comment: @Usernamenotfound they do print `val` before the conditional statement.

Comment: @hop the line after `val` is initiated is the `if` statement

Comment: i will do that real quick

Comment: @Usernamenotfound it really doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @hop I just noticed that it fails at the second conditional. You're right. I just wanted OP to see that it is an empty list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your Arduino is sending a blank line after the stop, which your script is not expecting - your script expects that every line will either have 'start', 'stop', or a list element. You can either look into what's happening on the Arduino and fix that, or update your script to ignore empty lines - after the `val = ...` line, add

```
if len(val) == 0:
    continue
```

Comment: it should be `if not val: continue`

Comment: @hop why is that better?

Comment: @lxop because Guido says so.

Comment: @hop source please?

Comment: @lxop: it's general knowledge, but if you must know, it's in pep8, for example

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your problem is within the output you posted. As you can see the last line of the output you posted is [] which is an empty list and does not have an element with index 0. Which means the item with index 0 which you try to grab, is not available or 'out of range'.

You have to change your while condition, so the loop stops after 'stop' is read.

Comment: so why does it happen randomly ?

Comment: I think lxop provided the simplest solution just add what he posted after val is read. That way it will continue reading but wont try to grab the value if nothing is there.